# ckeditor removes <br/> when br is in allowed content

Tags: ckeditor

When I add br to ckeditor allowed content and adding `<br>` tag it is being changed into `<br />`
But when I add `<br/>` it is being removed.

Why is it being removed when br is in allowed content? Any suggestions?

Comment: you can delete what's stripping the tags, or have the base language convert it to letters on the way out the door.

Comment: You might want to format your question - it appears that the newlines are rendered in the post. Try editing your question and format tags as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some bits missing from your post, not sure why, or what you were trying to say.

If what you were saying is that you wanted to add, say, `clear="all"` to your `<br />` tags,  you can use this to update your allowed content:

`config.AllowedContent = "br[clear]";`

Separate individual elements with `;`.

Here is the reference to the AllowedContent rules in the documentation:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules

I keep this bit in comments above my AllowedContent declaration as a reminder:

`elements [attributes]{styles}(classes)`

If that's not what you were asking, forgive me, again, there are some parts missing from your post.  If you can update it and let me know I'll revisit this answer.

== EDIT ==

Ok, I just looked at the edit of the post, and it seems you had "naked" `<br />` tags in your question, which turned into actual line breaks.

What you're seeing is that the editor is forcing valid HTML.  BR tags should *always* be formatted as such:  `<br />` (notice the space)

Comment: Thanks! so must I add the space on my content in order not to loose <br/> without spaces? Is there another way of keeping them?

Comment: Are you against using the space?  I always use the space, personally.  If you don't want to type the two extra characters, just leave type `<br>` and the editor will "fix" it for you.  Technically, a `<br>` tag is enough, but with the advent of HTML 5, I've switched to `<br />`.  I don't know why, but I prefer to see a self-closing tag, because it tells me that I'm not looking for a later end tag.  Might just be a personal preference.  I can't find anything that specifically says that `<br>` is wrong.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288460/html-whats-the-correct-form-of-br

Comment: The `<br>` tag is valid only in HTML, while the `<br />` tag is valid in both XHTML and HTML 5, so I just go with `<br />`.  Please vote up answers that help you, that's what keeps this site going!  ^_^

Comment: Thanks again - I'll use regexp to change it. I need it since sometimes my users can set <br/> and I don't want them to loose line breaks.