# ckeditor removes <br /> from code, cannot remove second space

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

Thanks for taking an interest. Here is the situation:

I'm receiving code from a client that contains `<br  />` (two spaces) in the content that has to be passed to ckreditor, when displayed ckreditor changes the `<br  />` element supplied from the code to `&nbsp`.

As the code is supplied by a third party and cannot be changed (without creating unexpected other steps that other developers won't be expecting, so I'd rather avoid `str_replace` based solutions) we cannot remove a space to the `<br  />` turning it into `<br />` as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163537/ckeditor-removes-br-when-br-is-in-allowed-content).

Here is an abbreviated example of what I receive:

```
<h2 dlpe-id="74">El plan perfecto0000 para una promoción única</h2>
                    <br  />
                    <br  />
                    <br  />
<div class="swiper-container" dlpe-id="78">...
```

And what is output by ckeditor:

```
<h2 dlpe-id="74">El plan perfecto0000 para una promoci&oacute;n &uacute;nica</h2>
<br  />
<br  />
&nbsp;
<div class="swiper-container" dlpe-id="78">...
```

Note the `&nbsp`. I've also seen in [this post](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/Editor-changing-html) that the config settings may be the key to solving this issue. Will post my config at the end of the question.

Any help to ensure the `<br/>` doesn't get turned into `&nbsp` by tweaking the config file or other means would be gladly appreciated.

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'links' },
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'others' },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'about' }
    ];

    // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
    // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
    config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Set the most common block elements.
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    // Simplify the dialog windows.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';

    config.autoParagraph = false;

    config.basicEntities = false;
    config.AllowedContent = "br[clear]";


};
```

Comment: Does the solution you are looking for should keep the two spaces inside the `br` element? `<br  />` or can it be one space?

Comment: Hi Dekel, I don't mind so long as the final `<br/>` isnt replaced with `&nbsp`, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this bug](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10146), it seems like it wasn't fixed yet (or might fixed and returned in newer versions).

However - from the comments there, 2 weeks ago j.swiderski added a comment with a code to fix this problem:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function( evt ){
    evt.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
        elements :{
            br : function( element ) {          
                //if next element is BR or <!--cke_br_comment-->, ignore it.
                if( element && element.next && ( element.next.name == 'br' || element.next.value == 'cke_br_comment' ) ){
                    return;
                }else {
                    var comment = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.comment( 'cke_br_comment' );
                    comment.insertAfter( element ); 
                }
            }
        }
    });

    evt.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
        elements :{
            li : function( element ) {
                if( element && element.next && element.next.name == 'br' ){
                    var nextElem = element.next;        
                    while( nextElem.next && nextElem.next.name == 'br' ){
                        nextElem = nextElem.next;
                    }
                    var comment = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.comment( 'cke_br_comment' );
                    comment.insertAfter( nextElem );    
                }
            }
        }
    }, 1 );//priority defaults to 10

    evt.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
        comment : function( value, node ) {
            if( value.indexOf('cke_br_comment') >= 0 ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

});

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/8xpfq4ng/

Comment: Hi Dekel, thanks for taking the time to code this, it is the end of the working day in our timezone and this is a team issue, will take a proper look tomorrow morning and provide feedback.

Comment: The jsfiddle is a working example, you can just open it and switch between the source/view mode several times to see how it works :) But you can also check it tomorrow. NP.