# How can I add a newline character to a String in Java?

Tags: java, html, string, line-breaks

In a Java application, I am creating a String like below (by concatenation):

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente;
```

My problem is that I want to add also something like an HTML newline character at the end of this String (that will be shown into an HTML page).

How can I implement it?

Comment: do like, dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "<br/>";

Comment: add <br/> tag will rendered on HTML page, like new line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newline character in Java is "\n" which will look like this:

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "\n";
```

However, this will not display as you expect on your HTML page. You can try adding an html break tag, or add the `&#10;` (Line Feed) and `&#13;` (Carriage Return) HTML entities:

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "<br>";
```

or

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "&#13;&#10";
```

Comment: No, the "newline character in Java" is `System.lineSeparator()`. `\n` is specifically for Unix/Linux/OSx/etc, while Windows uses `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

For a newline that will result in a line break in HTML, use

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "<br>";
```

For a newline that will result in a line break in your text editor, use

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + System.lineSeparator();
```

And for both, use

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "<br>" + System.lineSeparator();
```

**Why not `\n`?**

`\n` is specific to certain operating systems, while others use `\r\n`. `System.lineSeparator()` will get you the one that is relevant to the system where you are executing your application. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) for more info on this function, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for more info on newlines in general.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, need to add `<br/> (break line tag of HTML)`.

```
String notaCorrente = dataOdierna + " - " + testoNotaCorrente + "<br/>";
```

so, while you are going to display this content, `<br/> tag` will *rendered on HTML page in form of new line*.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but since he's asking about HTML and not XHTML, that should most likely be `<br>` and not `<br/>`. Both will work, but there's no point in not doing it in the way that is preferred. See this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288460/html-whats-the-correct-form-of-br